# Problem finding Undefined offset error in PHP code

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a hard time knowing why this error keeps happening and I don't know how to solve it. I already have seen this error on others posts but I didn't understand properly why.

The error is called

> `Undefined offset`

```
$emails = array();

$emailtosend = $db->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT username
    FROM wux_usersteams_tbl
    WHERE code = '".$team."'
");

if($emailtosend !== false) {
    while($result = $db->fetch_assoc($emailtosend)) {
        $emails[] = $result;
    }
    $db->free_result();
}

foreach($emails as $id => $email);
$cnt = 0;

if ($lang == 'pt'){
    $db->actionQuery("
        INSERT INTO wux_email_cron_tbl (email_id,ref_doc,ref_number,email_addresses,sender_name,
        cc,bcc,subject,message_text,sent,attachment_path,created_by,creation_date)
        VALUES 
        (".$emails.",
        '000',
        0,
        '".$emails[$cnt]["username"]."',
        'Carta de Crédito',
        '',
        '',
        'Carta de Crédito',
        '<p>O CLIENTE ".$client_name." ENVIOU UMA NOVA CARTA DE CRÉDITO (DRAFT DO SWIFT) RELACIONADA AO RFQ Nº ".$id_rfq." PARA ANÁLISE E APROVAÇÃO DA TRADING.</p>',
        0,
        '',
        '".$from."',
        date('now')) 
    ");
    
}else{
    $db->actionQuery("
        INSERT INTO wux_email_cron_tbl (email_id,ref_doc,ref_number,email_addresses,sender_name,
        cc,bcc,subject,message_text,sent,attachment_path,created_by,creation_date)
        VALUES
        (".$emails.",
        '000',
        0,
        '".$emails[$cnt]["username"]."',
        'Carta de Crédito',
        '',
        '',
        'CREDIT LETTER FILE',
        '<p>The Client ".$client_name." SEND A NEW CREDIT LETTER FILE (DRAFT DO SWIFT) RELATED TO RFQ NO ".$id_rfq." TO ANALISE AND APPROVAL TRADING.</p>',
        0,
        '',
        '".$from."',
        date('now'))
    ");
}
$cnt++;
$id_email++;
```

Comment: Does it tell you which line number has an undefined offset?

Comment: it says the error its on line 27 , the line 27 its this ".$emails."

Comment: Have you tried renaming it from `".$emails."` to `".$id."`? looks like it might be the wrong variable... 

Comment: It keeps giving the same error Undefined offset: 0 on line 27

Comment: offset generally will be indicating that of an array

Comment: Since your code (here) does not have line numbers, can you indicate the offending code line?

Comment: It's not related to the error, but `(".$emails.",` is wrong. You can't concatenate an array into a string.

Comment: The  offending code line is 27 : (".$emails.", inside the insert

Comment: So should i do a CAST?

Comment: Why are you using `$emails[$cnt]`, just use `$email`.

Comment: What are you intending that line to do? That's being inserted into the `email_id` column.

Comment: If that's an auto_increment column, you should just leave it out or specify `NULL` as the value to insert, and it will get an automatic ID.

Comment: You should also use prepared statements instead of substituting variables directly into the SQL.

Comment: Just to give some context the first line on the insert ".$emails."  is the id of the email and $emails[$cnt] is the email of the person plus the name,  should i switch it like you said ?

Comment: You shouldn't get `Undefined offset` from that use of `$emails`. Undefined offset always comes from accessing an invalid array index.

Comment: Why do you think `$emails` is the ID of the email? `$emails` is the array that you're looping through, `$id` is the array index, and `$email` is the current element of the array.

Comment: `$email['username']` is the username in the current array element.

Comment: What is `$id_email`? You're incrementing it in the loop, but you never initialized it.

Comment: The error you should be getting from that line is `Array to string conversion`

Comment: Im just trying to make sure that  i understand what are you saying , thats why im making so many question .

Comment: Honestly that's a mess of code.  You have a foreach that goes nowhere.  You are incrementing variables which appear to be in a foreach (but aren't).  You are defining the key $id but not using it.  This has at least 5 errors.

Comment: The $id_email i already correct to same variable .$emails.

Comment: Im just so confused right now. im gonna try to rewrite the code but im a disaster on php

Comment: Jut do small bits at a time and you will get there...

Comment: See my answer. The original problem is due to a typo, but there are lots of ways to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `;` at the end of the `foreach` line:

```
foreach($emails as $id => $email);
```

That's running a loop with an empty body. And the rest of the code is not inside the loop. It also means that you'll execute the code that uses `$emails[$cnt]` even if `$emails` is empty. That will cause the `Undefined offset` error.

Your code can also be simplified. The two `INSERT` queries are the same execpt for the language of some of the values being inserted. Use variables for those, so you don't have to repeat all the query code. `$lang` also doesn't change inside the loop, so you can set these variables once before the loop, rather than testing it every time.

Since you're only selecting one column from the table, you can just put that one value into the `$emails` array, rather than putting the whole row into the array.

To use an AUTO_INCREMENT `email_id`, you should specify `NULL` as the value being inserted, not `$emails`.

```
$emails = array();

$emailtosend = $db->query("
                SELECT DISTINCT username
                FROM wux_usersteams_tbl
                WHERE code = '".$team."'
         ");

if($emailtosend !== false) {
    while($result = $db->fetch_assoc($emailtosend)) {
        $emails[] = $result['username'];
    }
    $db->free_result();
}

if ($lang == 'pt'){
    $message = '<p>O CLIENTE ".$client_name." ENVIOU UMA NOVA CARTA DE CRÉDITO (DRAFT DO SWIFT) RELACIONADA AO RFQ Nº ".$id_rfq." PARA ANÁLISE E APROVAÇÃO DA TRADING.</p>';
    $subject = 'Carta de Crédito';
} else {
    $message = '<p>The Client ".$client_name." SEND A NEW CREDIT LETTER FILE (DRAFT DO SWIFT) RELATED TO RFQ NO ".$id_rfq." TO ANALISE AND APPROVAL TRADING.</p>';
    $subject = 'CREDIT LETTER FILE';
}

foreach($emails as $email) {
    $db->actionQuery("
                INSERT INTO wux_email_cron_tbl (email_id,ref_doc,ref_number,email_addresses,sender_name,
                                        cc,bcc,subject,message_text,sent,attachment_path,created_by,creation_date)
                VALUES 
                (NULL,
                '000',
                0,
                '".$email"',
                'Carta de Crédito',
                '',
                '',
                '".$subject."',
                '".$message."',
                0,
                '',
                '".$from."',
                 date('now')) 
            ");
}
```

Ideally you should be using a prepared statement instead of concatenating strings. But since you're using your own database class, I don't know if it supports this, so I can't show how to do it.

You actually don't even need the loop at all. You can use a `SELECT` query as the source of rows for `INSERT`. So the whole thing can be simplified to this:

```
if ($lang == 'pt'){
    $message = '<p>O CLIENTE ".$client_name." ENVIOU UMA NOVA CARTA DE CRÉDITO (DRAFT DO SWIFT) RELACIONADA AO RFQ Nº ".$id_rfq." PARA ANÁLISE E APROVAÇÃO DA TRADING.</p>';
    $subject = 'Carta de Crédito';
} else {
    $message = '<p>The Client ".$client_name." SEND A NEW CREDIT LETTER FILE (DRAFT DO SWIFT) RELATED TO RFQ NO ".$id_rfq." TO ANALISE AND APPROVAL TRADING.</p>';
    $subject = 'CREDIT LETTER FILE';
}

$db->query("
INSERT INTO wux_email_cron_tbl (email_id,ref_doc,ref_number,email_addresses,sender_name,
                                cc,bcc,subject,message_text,sent,attachment_path,created_by,creation_date)
SELECT DISTINCT NULL, '000', 0, username, 'Carta de Crédito', 
                '', '', '$subject', '$message', 0, '', '$from', CURRENT_DATE()
FROM wux_usersteams_tbl
WHERE code = '$team'");
```